# Pull data from Salesforce using javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce

Im trying hard on how can i pull data from salesforce using javascript.. any data that can be pulled  would  a good step! anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is via the REST APIs using the [ForceServer](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/11/forceserver-local-server-oauth-rest-development/).

Comment: Thaks @James Ward. I'll beep you for further questions.! cheers.